# Flood Fill 3D image on iOS App produces inconsistent fill output

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, image-processing

[MY CURRENT RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jztbn.jpg)------[DESIRED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFtRW.jpg).   I am building a mobile app that enables users to select a color from a palette and color parts of a 3D image like a room or wall.

I am currently using Opencv for iOS. I have created a Category for UIImage that fills from the point the User selects to the Closest color change. I know this problem requires further processing.

```
- (UIImage *)floodFillFromPoint:(cv::Mat)cvMat startPoint:(NSMutableArray* )startPoint endPoint:(NSMutableArray* )endPoint newColor:(ColorsRGB *)newcolor lodiff:(int )diff tap:(int )Taps
{
    cv::Mat cvMat2 = cvMat.clone();

    cv::cvtColor(cvMat, cvMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);//in-use

    cv::Mat mask;
    cv:: Mat edges;
    edges = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC1);
    cv::resize(cvMat, cvMat, cv::Size(500, 500));


    cv::Mat grad_x,grad_y,abs_grad_x,abs_grad_y;

        cv::Sobel(cvMat, grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0);
        cv::Sobel(cvMat, grad_y, CV_16S, 0, 1);


    cv::Canny(grad_x, grad_y,edges, 25, 70,3);

    cv::resize(edges, edges, cv::Size(500 + 2, 500 + 2));

    for (Pointed* obj in startPoint)
    {



        cv::Point seed(obj.point1,obj.point2);
        double red  = 255.0 * newcolor.red;
        double green  = 255.0 * newcolor.green;
        double blue  = 255.0 * newcolor.blue;

       cv::floodFill(cvMat,edges,seed, cv::Scalar(red,green,blue) ,0, cv::Scalar(2,2,2),cv::Scalar(1,1,1),4);



    }


    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
        bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | (
                                                   cvMat.elemSize() == 3? kCGImageAlphaNone : kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
                                                   );
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(
                                        cvMat.cols,                 
                                        cvMat.rows,                 
                                        8,                          
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),       
                                        cvMat.step[0],              
                                        colorSpace,                 
                                        bitmapInfo,                 
                                        provider,                   
                                        NULL,                      
                                        false,                      
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                        );

    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);


    return finalImage;
}
```

I expect a life like color on the wall with some level of smoothness and transparency. But my flood fill output contains holes and it fails completely when the light is bright.

Comment: show your gradx edges and all necessary debug infomation please. high chance its not because of flood function issue but pre processing issue

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai Hi, Yuan. I tried to output the gradx edges parameter, its all blank.

Comment: You have to scale it to the degree that you can see it. normally raw edge is 32F or 16U or 16S which you need to convert to 8U in order to see. My point is, somewhere in the initial segmentation part, there is a mistake/imperfection. you have to locate it and improve it

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai will this affect the output of the colour placed on the wall?

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai same output.